# Docker-compose does not snyc or apply changes to docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My question is why everytime I have changes to my leavelab folder, it does not reflect to my container. My container has a nodemon where it keep tracks my changes.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  app-rsync:
    build: ./docker
    volumes:
      - ./docker/leavelab:/usr/src/app # will be mounted on /usr/src/app/leavelab
```

This my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.8
EXPOSE 3000
LABEL org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0"
LABEL org.label-schema.docker.cmd="docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name alpine_leavelab"
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    git \
    make \
    nodejs npm \
    python \
    vim
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN adduser --system app --home /app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir /app/leavelab
COPY ./leavelab /app/leavelab
WORKDIR /app/leavelab
RUN npm install
CMD npm start
```

Comment: The directories in your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` don’t match.

Comment: yes it does not match but when you check my docker-compose:
version: "2"
services:
  app-rsync:
    build: ./docker

the build points to ./docker meaning inside the docker folder.

Comment: No, I mean, there are two copies of your application in the container.  `/app` is what comes from the Dockerfile, and what would run in production.  `/usr/src/app` is a mirror of your local development tree.

Comment: yah, I saw that. I already corrected it. :) Thanks for the feedback @David

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the topic like this: `docker-compose up` does not re-build the image for the specified `Dockerfile`.

My answer to this problem:

`docker-compose up` is only building images when there is no matching image, e.g. on the first `docker-compose up` call. You can enforce building with `docker-compose up --build`. You could also call `docker-compose build` before calling `docker-compose up`.